# SMS shows service center as null and send date well in the past

Tags: sms

I got this SMS today (actually twice in a gap of an hour) which had an empty body and shows as from contact number 0 with all other information being vague, like:

> Sent on 10 September 2011 
>   Received: 3 November 2015. 
>   Service center: null.

Does anybody have any explanation for this?

I'm using Android phone and MSP is Airtel India. Below is the screenshot.

[image: SMS message screen shot]

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to Android, it seems like a carrier error or some kind of control message.

Comment: I contacted carrier today but he said they're not having any kind of technical issue. I've got twice again after posting it here. 

You just said it may be some kind of control message. Could you please elaborate it a bit so that I may search for it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the issue was with the built-in Messaging app which was not showing the message as expected. I re-flashed the OS and it worked fine.